# How to find the area under the curve in R?

Tags: r

I have two columns X1 ,X2 .I want to find area under X1 and area under X2.

```
X = c(1,2,3,4,5)
Y1 = c(2,3,4,2,3)
Y2 = c(6,6,6,6,6)

plot(X,Y1) #Need to get area under this curve i.e auc(Y1)
plot(X,Y2) #Need to get area under this curve i.e auc(Y2)
```

I need this so as to I need to compare both areas i.e Y1 and Y2 by taking the ratio AUC(Y1)/AUC(Y2)

I need commulative area at each point.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that by `auc(Y1)` you mean the area under the curve seen in

```
plot(1:5,Y1,type = "l")
```

you can just use the [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule), which with step size 1 can be computed like thus:

```
auc <- function(y){
  n <- length(y)
  0.5*(y[1]+y[n]+2*sum(y[-c(1,n)]))
}
```

For example:

```
> auc(Y1)
[1] 11.5
```

Comment: Clever use of the trapezoidal rule.